# Installing Apache, MySQL (and secure it), PHP, phpMyAdmin in Amazon EC2

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

The reason for me posting this is I am really tired and wasted days trying to properly install a web server in amazon AWS `Amazon Linux AMI 2015.03 (HVM), SSD Volume Type` instance.

I have tried to install LAMP as mentioned in Tutorial: [Installing a LAMP Web Server on Amazon Linux and found I am still not able to access PHPMyadmin](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html).

Now for days I am trying to setup Apache, Apache Tomcat, MySQL, PhpMyAdmin and I always face troubles because 99% of the tutorials are written in 2012 and 100% outdated by now. Amazon tutorials are incomplete as they always are, so something is always left to find.I have almost opened and closed more than 4 instances, due to heavy "mess ups".

Can someone please point me to an "updated" tutorial which has the information of installing Apache, MySQL, PhyMyAdmin, PHP ? And of course I need to access these services from a URL, so remote access instructions also required.

Comment: This probaby belongs in server fault http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Have you considered launching an AMI (from the Marketplace) that already has a LAMP stack on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should consider running your setup on an Ubuntu instance, there are tons of tutorials for running a lamp stack on Ubuntu 14.04.

For instance, Digital Ocean Tutorials are a great resource: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

Next time please post this on serverfault.com .

Comment: Still, the remote access for PHPMyadmin is not there in the tutorial

Comment: @AlexT questions asking for tutorials or other off-site resources are off-topic here as well as at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed or flagged as such.